# UE4 C++ Can't seem to get overlap event to trigger

Tags: c++, collision-detection, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create an Actor that will represent a *zone* and have something happen to a vehicle that enters the *zone* (i.e. add money, activate a shop, etc.).

I **think** that I have everything set up correctly, but I can not seem to get the overlap event to trigger when the vehicle enters the *zone*.

Here is the code for the overlap event (**UE4.27.2**):

MyZone.h

```
public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyZone();

protected:
    
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = Target, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = true))
        TArray<class AVehiclePawn*> ActiveVehicles;

    UFUNCTION()
        virtual void OnVehicleEnteredZone(class UPrimitiveComponent* Comp, class AActor* OtherActor, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult);

    UFUNCTION()
        virtual void OnVehicleExitedZone(class UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, class AActor* OtherActor, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex);
```

MyZone.cpp

```
// Sets default values
AMyZone::AMyZone()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    CollisionShape = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("CollisionShape"));
    // Set collision on for this object but only for queries (overlaps and line traces etc)
    CollisionShape->SetCollisionEnabled(ECollisionEnabled::QueryOnly);
    // Remove collision for all channels
    CollisionShape->SetCollisionResponseToAllChannels(ECR_Ignore);
    // Now add back in overlap collisions for the pawn actor channel
    CollisionShape->SetCollisionResponseToChannel(ECC_Pawn, ECR_Overlap);

    Cast<UBoxComponent>(CollisionShape)->SetBoxExtent(FVector(500.f));

    // This is simply to show the item in game for dev purposes... Obviously this would be set to TRUE for production
    CollisionShape->SetHiddenInGame(false);

    //RootComponent = CollisionShape;
    RootComponent = Cast<USceneComponent>(CollisionShape);

    CollisionShape->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AMyZone::OnVehicleEnteredZone);
    CollisionShape->OnComponentEndOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AMyZone::OnVehicleExitedZone);
}

void AMyZone::OnVehicleEnteredZone(UPrimitiveComponent* Comp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    if (AVehiclePawn* VehiclePawn = CastChecked<AVehiclePawn>(OtherActor)) {
        this->ActiveVehicles.Add(VehiclePawn);

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("In FT Zone"));

        if (GEngine)
        {
            FString DebugMessage = FString("In FT Zone");
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, DebugMessage);
        }
    }
}

void AMyZone::OnVehicleExitedZone(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex)
{
    if (AVehiclePawn* VehiclePawn = CastChecked<AVehiclePawn>(OtherActor)) {
        this->ActiveVehicles.Remove(VehiclePawn);

        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Leaving FT Zone"));

        if (GEngine)
        {
            FString DebugMessage = FString("Leaving FT Zone");
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Red, DebugMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

AVehiclePawn is just an actor that extends AWheeledVehicle

The problem that I am encountering is that, when I put the *zone* into the game and run it, I was expecting it to show up in the on-screen text saying that I entered the zone. But nothing happens when I drive into it.
I thought that maybe something was up with the print to screen setup, so I also added the logging, and I am still seeing nothing when I drive into the *zone*.

Thanks in advance for any help. I am pulling my hair out here!

Thanks,

Brunke

Answer (score -1):

First thing, CollisionShape is of type UBoxComponent, you declare it here:  `CollisionShape = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("CollisionShape"));`

So this `Cast<UBoxComponent>(CollisionShape)->SetBoxExtent(FVector(500.f));`
is not needed. you can just access SetBoxExtent.

You may want to read about casting.

Furthermore, Unreal Engine doesn't really like binding events in constructor. Move it to BeginPlay, that typically helps.